# MVVM: Should the viewModel be architectured like the view or like the model

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, architecture

In our KnockoutJS project (a MVVM data-binding library) we have two types of viewModel that collides.
On one hand, we have viewModels that are architectured like the view. So let's say I have a form that allow me to create a user, it's a formVM. And each property of the viewModel is a property of the form. Each property is a computed that will write on the business model.

On the other hand, we have viewModels that are architectured like the business model. In our previous example, it would be a userVM, with the basic properties of the model plus other such as a label that is calculated from the username etc. And in the view html, we use here userVM.label for instance.

Is one more correct than the other? Which one do you use?

Answer (score 2):

I would say both are incorrect. There definetly shouldn't be any business logic in your viewmodels. This logic belongs in your business layer. The viewmodel should just hold a model (with observables bound to your form fields) and pass it to the business layer whenever appropriate.

Strictly speaking I'd say the viewmodel should only contain the model for your view (observables), event handlers, and very little else. When the user interacts with the UI, your event handlers will gather the necessary information and pass it to the business layer. This business layer might return data for the view, such as a calculated label that you mentioned. This value can then be inserted into a 'dumb' observable and therefore be displayed in the view without any business logic going into your viewmodel.

When the user hits save, you grab the data from the observables and pass it to the business layer, which will respond (changes saved succesfully, or something went wrong). The viewmodel can use this response to update the UI.

So in short, the viewmodel handles what the UI shows, and handles any interaction done by the user. But it typically only contains dumb functionality to pass the info along to the modules that contain the intelligence.

That's my view, and to be honest: in practise I violate this principe quite often myself.

Comment: Well, actually you're answering that the first approch is best. The fact that the viewmodel updates automatically the business model with computed is an implementation detail since I did not want to go into save button and such for the question. I'm myself quite fond of this philosophy as well, but my ex coworker use to arg that a VM based on the model can have properties that are reused among different view. For instance, if we show our labelUsername in the header and in the users panel, you don't have to specify the labelUsername computed twice nor to put a display logic in the business part

Comment: Well, that's something I should have mentioned: I would restrict the use of Knockout to your views/viewmodels. If you implement your business layer with Knockout (in this case the computed label), your business logic starts to depend on a library that was not meant for this. It will become virtually impossible to ever swap Knockout for, say, Angular, because Knockout will be nested into every layer of your application. The way the label is determined is something I would call business logic (debatable). So I'd make that a function, not an observable.

Comment: Oh, and of course you lose a bit of handy functionality, as you mentioned, multiple pieces of UI might need to be updated when the label changes. Normally binding against an observable would do this for you. The easiest way to do this without Knockout would be a publish/subscribe mechanism. Your viewmodels can subscribe to business layer events that concern them, and update their observables when those events are fired (e.g. `pubsub.subscribe('label-changed', function (newLabelValue) { myLabelObservable(newLabelValue); });` (or in short: `pubsub.subscribe('label-changed', myLabelObservable);`)